# Remote data received in composite disposable but not getting to the repository from callback.onResult

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I am using RxJava and PagedList for the first time. I followed through the tutorial by Riad as it is explanatory (Android Movie App MVVM). The only difference is that I had to create my viewmodel factory differently as `ViewModelProviders.of()` that he used is deprecated.

The main issue is that I can see that the response from the Api is collected but does not get to my repository and viewmodel. I have tried to debug and find reason why this happening but could not figure it out.

Perhaps there is something am missing that I could helped with

### Datasource

```
class MovieDataSource(private val apiService:TheMovieDbInterface, private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable):PageKeyedDataSource<Int, Movies>() {

    var page = FIRST_PAGE
    val networkState = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()
    override fun loadInitial(
        params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
        callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, Movies>
    ) {
        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING)


        try {
            compositeDisposable.add(
                apiService.getPopularMovies(page)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe({it->
                        callback.onResult(it.results, null, page+1)
                        Log.i("MovieDetailsResponse", "${it.results}")
                        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)
                    },{
                        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.ERROR)
                        Log.e("MovieDetailsResponse", it.message)
                    })
            )
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            Log.e("MovieDetailsResponse", e.message)
        }
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, Movies>) {
        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING)


        try {
            compositeDisposable.add(
                apiService.getPopularMovies(params.key)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe({it->
                        if(it.totalPages >= params.key){
                            callback.onResult(it.results,  params.key+1)
                            networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)
                        }
                        else{
                            networkState.postValue(NetworkState.END_OF_LIST)
                        }
                    },{
                        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.ERROR)
                        Log.e("MovieDetailsResponse", it.message)
                    })
            )
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            Log.e("MovieDetailsResponse", e.message)
        }
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, Movies>) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

### DataSourceFactory

```
class MovieDataSourceFactory(private val apiService: TheMovieDbInterface, private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable):DataSource.Factory<Int, Movies>() {

    val movieLiveDataSource = MutableLiveData<MovieDataSource>()
    override fun create(): DataSource<Int, Movies> {
        val movieDataSource = MovieDataSource(apiService, compositeDisposable)
        movieLiveDataSource.postValue(movieDataSource)
        return movieDataSource
    }
}
```

### PagedListRepository

```
lass MoviePagedListRepository(private val apiService:TheMovieDbInterface) {

    lateinit var moviePagedList:LiveData<PagedList<Movies>>
    lateinit var movieDataSourceFactory: MovieDataSourceFactory

    fun fetchLiveMoviePagedList(compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable):LiveData<PagedList<Movies>>{
        movieDataSourceFactory = MovieDataSourceFactory(apiService, compositeDisposable)
        val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setPageSize(POST_PER_PAGE)
            .build()

        moviePagedList = LivePagedListBuilder(movieDataSourceFactory, config).build()
        Log.i("moviePagedList", "$moviePagedList")
        return moviePagedList
    }
    fun getNetworkState():LiveData<NetworkState>{
        return Transformations.switchMap<MovieDataSource, NetworkState>(
            movieDataSourceFactory.movieLiveDataSource, MovieDataSource::networkState
        )
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel(private val movieRepository:MoviePagedListRepository): ViewModel() {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    val moviePagedList : LiveData<PagedList<Movies>> = movieRepository.fetchLiveMoviePagedList(compositeDisposable)


    val networkState:LiveData<NetworkState> by lazy {
        movieRepository.getNetworkState()
    }

    fun isListEmpty():Boolean{
        return moviePagedList.value?.isEmpty()?: true
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()

        compositeDisposable.dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have two calls executed ? one with the first page of the data, and the second one with an empty data list because your page two is empty ?

Comment: nope I have not even seen page one

Comment: briefly looking, remove the the `TODO` in `loadBefore` hook - this will throw error when called. Also `subscribeOn` is probably not needed in the load callbacks as I think they are called using a cached thread pool anyway (not main thread) - just use in a blocking fashion.

Comment: @MarkKeen thanks for your suggestion. It works. I can now get the data from the observer except that my pagedlist is not triggered through the submitList function.